# Retrieve videos based on Content Title on the Block

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-8, page-title

I am using Drupal 8

I kept getting all of videos on the block on the first sidebar of the Article page.  I want video to be picked up when it matches with Content Title of Article.  When I entered a title on preview contextual filter while I was working on the structure view for the block, it came out right   But it still lists all videos regardless of Content Title on the block of Article.

In two content types, I set it up as shown:

**Article   Content Type**

- Content Title

**Video Reference Content Type**

- Title    field_title   Entity Reference  to Content Title of Article,
- Video

**Relationships:**

- Field_title: Content
- (field_title: Content) field-title

**Contextual Filters:**

- (field_title: Content) Content:  Title

It appears I am very close because whenever I type the title on the contextual filter on the view structure page. It came OK.  Whenever I go back to the content article page, the block still is showing all videos.   I believe it displays all because it could not found as in the default.

Answer (score -1):

As my understand i guess u should override your (article)block which u created.

May be this link - https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions helped u for overriding block after overriding block according to article node(eg. node/111) u will get your videos which present in that node.

Note- **don't remove contextual filter from view.**

Hope this will help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should explain the answer in your post instead of simply directing someone to a link. Links should only be used as a 'source to refer to' instead of 'please read this link.'

Comment: Thanks,  I guess I have to learn how twig works.   If you have good example on how to override to get matched content title, I appreciate this.